# Make one side of svg rounded

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make one side of my svg to be rounded.

I have svg below and I want to rounded this part:

[image]

How can I do this?

My svg size must be 100% of it's container.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
polygon {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="10,0 40,0 40,100 10,80"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skew transformation with border radius can easily do this:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:20px;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:right;
  transform:skewY(10deg);
  background:black;
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you create SVG-file, then use a graphical editor.
- If you create the element in CSS, then:

`border-top-left-radius: 60px 100%; // no slash on individual radius properties, mix-and-match with pixel and percent measures
border-top-right-radius: 10% 40%; // border will sometimes reflow to fit curve
border-bottom-left-radius: 300px 100px; // radius measurements larger than the shape itself can be declared
border-bottom-right-radius: 10%; // you can mix and match with regular radius statements`